# External JS file not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, erb, jbuilder

Im having trouble gettin my external JS file to fire when I trigger it with an onclick event.

The JS file is in the same directory as the html file.

Here's the html:

```
<head>
  <script src='request.js'></script>
</head>

<h1>Requests</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Votecount</th>
      <th>Vote for Song</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @requests.each do |request| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= request.artist %></td>
        <td><%= request.title %></td>
        <td class="voteCount"><%= request.voteCount %></td>
        <td><button onclick="upVote()">Vote</button></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's what's in my JS file:

```
function upVote() {
        alert("firing trigger");
        var count = document.getElementsByClassName("voteCount")[0].innerHTML;
        count = parseInt(count);
        count = count + 1;
        count = count.toString();
        document.getElementsByClassName("voteCount")[0].innerHTML = count;
  }
```

Here's my directory list:
[image: Directories]

Comment: You gonna have to show us the JavaScript too.

Comment: Besides the missing body and HTML tags, one thing that stands out is that button doesn't have a type. Which means button is setup as SUBMIT which would cause issues. Try adding type="button" to your button

Comment: You may need to add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> before the close of the body tag...?

Comment: Where in your HTML are you referring to your **file**?

Comment: Im referencing it in the head, but i just moved it to the end of the body and its still not working

Comment: open your browser's console (usually F12 on Windows) and refresh the page and click it to see if there are errors.

Comment: I updated the type to button as well.

Comment: Looks like im getting a 404 error when the page tries to load that file. It's in the same directory so im not sure why it wouldnt be finding it

Comment: @KatyH. why would you have to add jQuery when there is no jQuery used????

Comment: This might be an issue with your Ruby Editor and how it generates the html files. You are making this using Embeddable Ruby right?

Comment: Look at the developer console for errors. See if there is a 404 with the js file in the network tab

Answer (score 0):

With Rails there is an assets folder where the external JS files need to be stored.

```
app/assets/javascripts
```

Answer (score -1):

This happening because the code is executed before the `DOM` is generated. Try to move the `<script src='request.js'></script>` to end of the `<body>`

```
<body>

<h1>Requests</h1>

<table>
  ...
  ...
</table>
<script src='request.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: added the file to my post